# How to use hasOwnProperty with AngularJS Directive `attrs` object

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a directive named `ip-abc` which is used to check the input values of fields and convert to dollar formatted values. I have a condition where if we have the value as "0", then I will convert that to $0.

**ipabc.js**

```
var filterFunc = function (value) {
    if(value == '0'){
    if(attrs.hasOwnProperty('ipZeroDollar')){
       var currencyValue = $filter('currency')(value);
       currencyValue = currencyValue.toString();
       return currencyValue.replace('.00','');
    } 
}
```

The problem which I am facing is that, how can I set `ipZeroDollar = true` in HTML. As of now, `(attrs.hasOwnProperty('ipZeroDollar'))` is coming as `false`.

```
<div ng-class = {'//something'}
  <input type="tel" name="amount" class="form-control" ng 
   model="Data.Amount" maxlength="15" required ip-abc/>
</div>
```

Comment: Where does `attrs` come from? In any case, it's unlikely to have that as a **property**. More likely an *entry*. (E.g., more likely `attrs` is a list of name/value pairs. It certainly is [in the DOM](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NamedNodeMap) but I wouldn't know about an Angular thing...)

Comment: If attrs is an object containing the attributes of the `<input>` HTML tag, change the name into 'data-ipzerodollar' and change the input into `<input data-ipZeroDollar="someValue" />`. But maybe something like `data-currency="ipzerodollar"` might even be better so that you can support multiple currencies but only one attribute. Then again, I'm not even sure if this makes sense as a data-attribute to begin with when using angular. I also do not understand using a telephone input to depict a currency value.

Answer (score 1):

> The problem which I am facing is that, how can I set `ipZeroDollar = true` in HTML. As of now, `(attrs.hasOwnProperty('ipZeroDollar'))` is coming as false.

The [camelCase](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Camel_case) needs to be normalized to [kebab-case](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Letter_case#Special_case_styles) in the HTML:

```
<input type="tel" name="amount" class="form-control"
       ng-model="Data.Amount" maxlength="15" required
       ip-abc  ip-zero-dollar />
```

For more information, see

- [AngularJS Developer Guide - Attribute Normalization](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive#normalization)
- [AngularJS `attrs` Type API Reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$compile.directive.Attributes)

### The DEMO

```js
angular.module("app",[])
.directive("ipAbc", function() {
    return {link: postLink};
    function postLink(scope,elem,attrs) {
      var hasIpZeroDollar = attrs.hasOwnProperty("ipZeroDollar");
      console.log("hasIpZeroDollar",hasIpZeroDollar);
    }
})
```

```html
<script src="//unpkg.com/angular/angular.js"></script>
<body ng-app="app"
    <input type="tel" name="amount" class="form-control"
           ng-model="Data.Amount" maxlength="15" required
           ip-abc ip-zero-dollar />
</body>
```

Comment: If this works, please accept the answer so that others will know that the problem is solved.

Answer (score 0):

This is how you use hasOwnProperty().

```
let obj = {color: 'yellow'}
obj.hasOwnProperty('color') // returns true
```

It seems like you would want to call `hasOwnProperty()` on `Data` since that looks like its an object, and that is where you are getting the amount.